# Arrays vs. Doubly Linked Lists for Queue simulation

Tags: c++, arrays, queue, doubly-linked-list

I am working on an assignment for school simulating a line with students and multiple windows open at the Registrar's Office.

I got the queue for the students down but it was suggested by someone that I use an array for the windows implementing our queue class we made on our own.
I don't understand why an array would work when there are other variables I want to know about each window besides just the student time decrementing.

I'm just looking for some direction or more in depth explanation on how that's possible to use an array to just store the time each student is at the window as opposed to another doubly linked list?

Comment: At least make your questions clear from this ugly wall of text.

Comment: I tried to make it very clear but I explained the situation first.. I will try and edit tho to make clearer..

Comment: You heard about these things called _paragraphs_ and other text formatting options, to make text readable for humans?

Comment: Yes I did that when I typed it but it didn't show up correctly. No need to be rude. I shortened it now and will just post my other question separately. I'm still somewhat new so I'm just trying to get used to this is all...

Comment: Can you delete the down vote now?

Comment: Well, you can use a `std::queue<std::shared_ptr<Student>>` to represent the queue of students waiting at the counter window. Note that `std::queue` actually uses an underlying array (std::vector) by default. It's still unclear what you're actually asking about. You may be should give a code sample to make it better understand about what you're actually after. (See my edits how to structure it better BTW)

Comment: Ok well the issue is that we have to use our own queue class. He doesn't want us using the STL library.  I see your edits. I will work on making shorter paragraphs for future posts. Thanks. And I was trying to figure out the process first on paper before doing a bunch of code or else I usually do include my code.

Comment: I was trying to see if it was possible to create a windows class and create an array of each new window class. Is that incorrect/inefficient?

Comment: If a queue simulation, why not a single-linked list?

Comment: Is that the most efficient way? That's what I'm trying to figure out... And with the least run time

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you've got a variable number of students and a fixed number of windows (buildings don't usually change all that often). If I were to make a representation of this in code I would use a dynamically sized container (a list, vector, queue, etc.) to contain all the students and a fixed-size array for the registers. This would embody the intent of the real situation in code, making it less likely that someone else using your code makes any mistakes related to the size of the Registrar's Office. Often choosing a container type is all about its intended use!

Thus you can design a class to hold all the registers using a fixed-size array (or even nicer: a template-dictated size seeing as your using C++). Then you can write all your other Registrar-related functions using the given size argument and thus never go out-of-bounds in your Registrar-array.

Lastly: an array holds whatever information you want it to hold. You can have it hold only numbers (like int) but you can also have it hold objects of any type! What I mean to say is: create a Registrar class that holds all the information you want to collect for every individual Registrar. Then create an array that holds Registrar objects. Then whenever you access an individual element in the array you can access all the information of the individual Registrar through that single reference.